# Dialog window with text field in Jira serlvet

Tags: servlets, jira, url-parameters

I made a Jira servlet that executes a search in an issue, but I want to be able to add a filter to that search, so I need to be able to get text as a parameter before I execute the search.

Is there a way for me to make it so a dialog window with a `text field` and an `OK` button pops up when I press the servlet button, and the request executes after I press the said button, with an empty string or the current string as a parameter?

Actually any way of dynamically setting a parameter before the request executes might help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want to use the InlineDialog pattern.  Have a look at [Atlassian's AUI Sandbox](https://docs.atlassian.com/aui/latest/sandbox/) for an example.

Something like this should do the trick in a recent version of JIRA

Button HTML:

```
<button class="aui-button " href="#" id="popupLink">
    <span class="aui-icon aui-icon-small aui-iconfont-search-small">Search</span> Search on this issue
</button>
```

Behaviour JavaScript:

```
AJS.InlineDialog(AJS.$("#popupLink"), 1,
    function(content, trigger, showPopup) {
        content.css({"padding":"20px"}).html(
            '<h2>Search something</h2>'
            + '<form action="/path/to/your/servlet" method="get">'
            +   '<input name="q" placeholder="Search query..." >'
            +   '<input type="submit" value="Search">'
            + '</form>'
        );
        showPopup();
        return false;
    }
);
```

This should give you an InlineDialog similar to the image below:

[image]

Also by adding a `data-default-value` attribute to your button, you could easily prepopulate the search field in the InlineDialog.